# Change background image to grayscale but not the color background overlay (elementor)

Tags: css, elementor

I have a client that wants a lot of **background images in grayscale** with a **color overlay** (gradient or solid). I thought it would be great to do this via CSS rather than having to convert every image to grayscale and uploading them to the site.

I have attempted to do so here (https://solair.inventivewd.com/about-us)  but am not understanding how the CSS works.

We are using WordPress with the Astra Theme and Elementor.

You can see towards the top of the page there is a box in grayscale and a box in color. Each of these is a column with a background image and translucent background color overlay. I am just using some simple CSS to convert to grayscale. The middle column has been assigned a class of `bw`:

```
.bw .elementor-widget-wrap {
    filter: grayscale(1);
}

.bw .elementor-background-overlay {
    filter: grayscale(0) !important;
}
```

This seems like it should change the grayscale filter on the **color background overlay** but it doesn't. Can anyone help?

Here is the HTML code for the grayscale section:

```
<div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-971fbac bw elementor-motion-effects-parent" data-id="971fbac" data-element_type="column" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;motion_fx_motion_fx_scrolling&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;motion_fx_translateY_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;motion_fx_translateY_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:1,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]},&quot;motion_fx_translateY_affectedRange&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;%&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:{&quot;start&quot;:0,&quot;end&quot;:100}},&quot;motion_fx_devices&quot;:[&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;tablet&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;]}">
    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated elementor-motion-effects-element" style="--translateY:10.5px; --e-transform-transition-duration:100ms; transform: translateY(var(--translateY));">
        <div class="elementor-background-overlay"></div>
        <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-815fd81 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="815fd81" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                <h3 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Mission</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-b0f7845 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="b0f7845" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <p>Sample Text</p>                      
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to to add the filter in the DevTools of chrome and it worked without any problem.

[image]

Try to add -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) so it should be compatible for safari to.
Internet Explorer has problems with -webkit-filter and filter and for me it doesn't work either way in there.
But theres surely a solution in the internet what you can do that filter works in internet explorer.

Comment: I don't think this is the effect I am looking for. Your screenshot looks just like the center col that I have (all grayscale). What I am looking for is a Grayscale Image with a translucent Color Overlay. I was going to add all the versions of grayscale filters after I saw that it works on not.